# Making simple dynamic search bar with values according to function

Tags: javascript, angular

Long story short, I have this `div` inside my `app.component.html`:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 search-div">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which shows:

[image: searchImage]

And I would like for it to show available values according to a function I have in the my `app.component.ts`:

```
public getUsers() {
  return this.restService.getUsers().subscribe(
    jsonElements => {
      var users = jsonElements;
    },
    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

I can even pre-store the result:
`users = this.getUsers();`
But then how would I filter by `users`?

Is there an easy way to accomplish this ?

Comment: Turn it into a select object https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUBsn0_Ce94

Answer (score 0):

There is already an HTML solution for what you want, the 'datalist' tag does what you want. The only problem with it is that it does not have great browser support. You can read more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist.

So you would use it like

```
<input list="users"/></label>
<datalist>
    <option *ngFor='let user of users' value="user">
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for an autocomplete.

You can find an example [here](https://github.com/ng2-ui/ng2-auto-complete) with a plunker but others are available as well.